# SQL Distinct is not removing duplicated elements. Why?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, distinct

I'm using the following query:

```
$cities = $wpdb->get_results( "select distinct ID , post_title from $wpdb->posts where post_type = 'place' and post_parent = $state_id order by post_title ", ARRAY_A );
```

But the duplicated elements are not removed. Why ?
Here's the whole usage:

```
<label for="veneue_finder_city_select">Cityyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</label>
                            <select id="veneue_finder_city_select" name="city_id">
                                <option value="">Any</option>
                                <?php
                                if( !empty($state_id) ) {

                                    $states = array();
                                    $cities = $wpdb->get_results( "select distinct ID , post_title from $wpdb->posts where post_type = 'place' and post_parent = $state_id order by post_title ", ARRAY_A );

                                    foreach( $cities as $city ):
                                    ?>

                                        <option value="<?php echo $city['ID']; ?>" <?php selected($city['ID'], $city_id) ?>><?php echo $city['post_title']; ?></option>
                                    <?php endforeach;
                                }?>
                            </select>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your result? Which part is duplicated?

Comment: Because of ID ;) Every post has different ID - am i right?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  You probably just don't understand what `select distinct` does.

Comment: I have duplicated towns like : Berlin Berlin Berlin etc..

Comment: @RumenPanchev: with different `ID`s?

Comment: You only want the cities? So remove the `ID` from `SELECT` and you get distinct values.

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: I want to remove the duplicated towns like Berlin Berlin Berlin etc..

Comment: try this `$cities = $wpdb->get_results( "select distinct post_title from $wpdb->posts where post_type = 'place' and post_parent = $state_id order by post_title ", ARRAY_A );`

Comment: Same think bro. Cannot remove duplicated elements

Comment: can you post the result of your query? `print_r($cities);`

Comment: when i use print_r nothing happens. They're not printing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147080/discussion-between-b-7-and-rumen-panchev).